# SSRS Report Date Formate using X++

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, report, x++

please help me. I am doing MS Dynamics D365 Report laypot. I have a date that I want to set for a specific formate - YYYY/MM/DD.  I can get that formate but I have the time in the end. I just want date formate to be  YYYY/MM/DD only with out time at the end. I am using DateTimeUtill to string for converting the date, since the date is a datetime formate in MS Dynamics D365 system. How can I convert the date to YYYY/MM/DD??. As I want a single ine code that can converted. Please help. Thanks

[report layout having YYYY/MM/DD + time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sIk4.png)

Here is my code:

```
 PurchPurchaseOrderHeader.Notes += "Rev " + int2Str(counterforrevisiondate) 
                + ": " + DateTimeUtil::toStr(vendPurchOrderJour.PurchOrderDate) + "\n";
```

I am expecting the date to have datetime formate of YYYY/MM/DD without the time in the end. But it did not expect that way.

Comment: Yes, I try this as well. It works. But this was a bit different from my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strFmt("%1", DateTimeUtil::date(vendPurchOrderJour.PurchOrderDate)) ?
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works!!!! I want to upvote youu!!! :) But not enough of reputation.